# I can't see colors in zsh through SSH

Tags: ssh, zsh

I recently moved from bash to ZSH and oh-my-zsh (which is so far wonderful) and installed it in my desktop, laptop and hosting (dreamhost) with a theme called agnoster.

I also installed solarized and the custom powerline-patched font in both gnome-terminal (Dekstop) and iTerm2 (OSX), so in both o these I get everything to work just fine

[image]

and even if I use SSH to connect to my Desktop from my laptop I see everything working.

The problem is, when I changed the default shell in Dreamhost to zsh, installed oh-my-zsh and agnoster, it just shows:

```
{black}{default} user@dreamhost {blue}{black}⮀{black} ~ {blue}⮀
```

[image]

(The arrows work for me) but the colors are not shown properly, just as a string.

I have looked for a solution everywhere but I can't seem to find what is causing this, did anyone ever encounter such a problem or knows any way to fix this?

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: Can you clarify please? Zsh is a shell, not a terminal. If you changed your *terminal* to zsh, change it back; if you changed your default *shell* to zsh, please edit your question.

Comment: @dave4420 my bad, I actually meant I changed my default shell to zsh (from bash, which was the default) from the dreamhost control panel

Comment: Additional information is probably required. Check the `zsh` version (`zsh --version`) both locally and remotely. Are you using identical zsh files on both boxes (and how sure are you about that)? What are the `zsh` options (`setopt`)? What does the code for the `PROMPT` look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it!

Thanks to @simont for giving me the clue about what the problem could be about: **Version**!

I did as he said and run `zsh --version` on both working machines and Dreamhost, resulting in Dreamhost having `4.3.6`, which is far lower than the `5.0.0` version found on the working machines.

## Solution Steps

1. SSH Dreamhost
2. Download the latest version of zsh from [their website](http://www.zsh.org/). (use wget, curl ...)
3. Extract everything `tar zxfv zsg.tar.gz`
4. `cd zsh/`
5. `./configure --prefix=$HOME/local`
6. `make`
7. `make install`

Now just change your SSH command to `ssh username@host.dreamhost.com -t local/bin/zsh`
 or, as I did, make a new alias in your local machine (be it `~/.bashrc`, `~/.zshrc` or whichever shell you use) to avoid the extra typing.

Thanks a lot guys for your help!